# How to "sample" a value in VHDL?

Tags: case, vhdl, counter

So I have a modulo counter going from 1->15, then looping back around constantly in a seperate entity. I would like to, in a case statement depending on some outputs, sample this value on the rising_edge of a clock, but only do it once, otherwise the value will be constantly changing. Is there a way to do this? Assign the signal and have it stay static?
I've posted some code that I hope will demonstrate what I am trying to say a bit better.

```
process(all) 
      begin --sensitivity list?
      if(reset) then
          playerCards <= "0000000000000000";
          dealerCards <= "0000000000000000";
      elsif rising_edge(clock) then
        case? deal & dealTo & dealToCardSlot is
          when "1100" =>
            playerCards(3 downto 0) <= singleCard;
                    playerCards(15 downto 4) <= (others => '0');
          when "1101" =>
            playerCards(7 downto 4) <= singleCard;
                    playerCards(15 downto 8) <= (others => '0');
          when "1110" =>
            playerCards(11 downto 8) <= singleCard;
                    playerCards(15 downto 12) <= (others => '0');
          when "1111" =>
            playerCards(15 downto 12) <= singleCard;
          when "1000" =>
            dealerCards(3 downto 0)   <= singleCard; --dcard1
            dealerCards( 15 downto 4) <= (others => '0');
          when "1001" =>
            dealerCards(7 downto 4)   <= singleCard; --dcard2
            dealerCards( 15 downto 8) <= (others => '0');
          when "1010" =>
            dealerCards(11 downto 8)  <= singleCard; --dcard3
            dealerCards( 15 downto 12) <= (others => '0');
          when "1011" =>
            dealerCards(15 downto 12) <= singleCard; --dcard4
          when "0--0" => null;                       --do nothing when in win/end
          when others => --this covers the start case --sets cards to 0
            playerCards <= "0000000000000000";
            dealerCards <= "0000000000000000"; 
        end case?;
      end if;
  end process;
```

Here I have singleCard being linked to the output of my counter, which increments every clock edge. So basically I would like my case statement to only happen update the value of playerCards once, and then stop.
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your requirement can be stated as : the process can be in two states - sampling, or not sampling, and to transition to not sampling when you sample.

So you can do this with a state variable, which in this case can be a boolean - this turns your process into a state machine. As the other answer says, you can use a signal here instead of a variable, but that breaks encapsulation, making the processes internal workings visible.

Some people would insist you separate out the state machine into another two (or even 3) processes, but I think the single process form is a lot smaller and easier to understand.

```
   process(reset,clock) -- original sens list is incorrect for a clocked process
   variable sampling : boolean;
   begin 
      if(reset) then
          sampling <= true;
          -- other reset actions
      elsif rising_edge(clock) then
         if sampling then   -- add conditions here, or it'll sample on the first clock.
            sampling := false;
            case ... -- sampling process and program logic
            end case;
         else
            -- if you need to turn sampling back on, set "sampling" here
         end if;
      end if;
   end process;
```

Comment: Would his be a sort of state machine inside my datapath then? I'm asking this as supposedly (this is for a school lab), it can be done without adding anymore signals between my FSM and datapath. I was wondering if something like a deal'event & dealTo'event & dealToCardSlot'event would work? Currently my FSM transistions on a button press, where I use a very similar FSM to the one you described, then the values of deal/dealTo/dealToCardSlot are updated. Thanks for the help, I've been stuck on this for a number of days now.

Comment: `deal'event & dealTo'event & dealToCardSlot'event` sounds like a very bad idea to me, normally you only look for 'event on a clock signal, and concatenating events into an aggregate is ... weird. What for?

Comment: Since deal,dealTo,dealToCardSlot hold their values for multiple clock cycles, the case statement is constantly assigning singleCard to my playerCards signal. I'm just wondering if there is a way to have a constant type perhaps, that once assigned cannot change anymore?

Comment: Of course! That's what the process above does (after the typing errors are fixed, which I just did. Sorry about those). If you mean, move that behaviour to the type itself rather than in the state machine above, sorry, no. Constantness is orthogonal to type. If you have a separate state machine, it might make sense to move the update/not-update logic there.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need an additional *internal signal* that will control your operation mode: *updating* and *non-updating*.

It would be actually a kind of *feedback signal*. You generate it depending on the input conditions, and then you also use it on input to modify the behaviour.